# how do I use *args when working with a string

Tags: python

I tried to use the *args when working with a list of strings and the output remained a tuple. I'm trying ensure that all letters in the string are uppercase but I cant figure it out
I tried tuple unpacking but it doesn't work on an indefinite number of objects

Comment: No idea what you are talking about. Add a [mcve]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*args is used to pass variable number of arguments to a function. Here's a reference article: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/

As far as working with a function that has a *args of strings, since *args groups its arguments into a tuple, you would need to access and operate on each string individually.